# {order_id} in CartThrob not using correct ID

Tags: add-on, cartthrob

I have the radio button for "Create sequential order/invoice numbers" and it is adding the proper order id to the entry title, but I'd like {order_id} to return that as well.

order_id column in exp_cartthrob_order_items has a completely different number.

For instance:

"Last Order Number" field shows the next ID should be 548. In the DB the last order_id was 3487. As I said, the 548 is showing up as the entry title, just not saving as the order id. Any thoughts?

R

Comment: What version of CT are you using? And when you say "in the DB", where are you looking -- in the actual database, or in EE admin area?

Comment: Sorry, latest version: 2.2.9.

Comment: Both. The last order number is a field in the CT order settings. I was comparing to the order_id column in the exp_cartthrob_order_items table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `{order_id}` corresponds to the `{entry_id}`, not the 'order number' in the title.
As far as I know, you can't get that number in your templates.

However, you could change your title prefix from lets say "Order #" to just blank, then in your template just reference `{title}`.

Then instead of just using `<h1>{title}</h1>`, you'd use `<h1>Order #{title}</h1>`.

Comment: I thought this to be the case as well, however, in my latest "order," `order_id = 3487` and `entry_id = 3432`. That is why I thought to bring it up.

Comment: Ah weird, might want to get an official response then.

Comment: Ok, just kidding. I'm a moron. I was looking at the `entry_id` of the purchased product.

Comment: @RyanShrum Please post your solution as an answer and select your answer as correct by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Comment: @Anna_MediaGirl - Jason's above answer was correct. The order_id is the entry_id - order # is a separate integer.

Comment: @RyanShrum If you believe my answer is correct then could you please mark it as accepted? :) Thanks.